# compare two images using Selenium Ruby Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

Please help give me a solution to compare if two images in two URLs of an Web application are identical (I mean that content in each image are identical) or not by using Selenium Ruby Webdriver.

ex: I have a small image displayed when accessing the URL below:

```
 http://testing.com/image1.png
```

I also have another image when accessing the URL below:

```
 http://testing.com/image2.png
```

How can I compare these two images to see if they are identical using Selenium Ruby Webdriver ? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks much.

Comment: This is not something the WebDriver was designed for, but there are workarounds. maybe something like downloading the images through a Ruby library, get a hash of both files and compare it. If the hashes match, it's the same file.

Comment: Images being "identical" is actually a slippery concept, unless you mean very simply that `image1.png` and `image2.png` are in fact the same file (or exact copies). Your wording implies for your case that one might be a different size to the other, perhaps a thumbnail link - is that the case?

Comment: If your images are reasonably sized and you are testing for exact copies, you could just use `require 'open-uri'; def compare(a,b); open(a).read == open(b).read; end`.

Comment: Hi Neil Slater, Images being "identical", I mean that content in each image are the same (ex: imageA includes some points displayed on it, then imageB also contains points exactly the same as the imageA).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Arran, as your first suggestion, I'm able to download images successfully, but the main problem is that I would like to compare that the content in each image is identical, so it seems that it does not work when I get hash of files to compare, because each image always have a Unique Hash, and I always get "False" value returned when trying to comparing content of these two images with code like: log File.open('abc_test_AA.jpg').hash == File.open('abc_test_AA.jpg').hash. So, Could you please guide me another way to compare two images ? Thanks so much.

Comment: @battleship: To clarify "Contains the same points" (which technically could mean several different things): 1) The images are exactly the same height and width? 2) Each pixel is supposed to have identical RGB value?

Comment: @Neil Slater: Yes, the images are exactly the same height and width, and each pixel is supposed to have identical RGB value.

Comment: More, you can use these files md5 comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rmagick` can be used to compare two images for identical pixels, using the `compare_channel` method:

```
img1 =  Magick::Image.read('image1.png')
img2 =  Magick::Image.read('image2.png')

diff_img, diff_metric  = img1[0].compare_channel( img2[0], Magick::MeanSquaredErrorMetric )

# diff_img is a cool feature - an image showing which pixels are different

# diff_metric == 0.0 for "no difference"
```

See http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#compare_channel for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much to response and give me this great solution. As my googling, to use Magick and apply to my Selenium Ruby Script, now I need to do something like below:
1. install ImageMagick
2. install rmagick gem
3. then, in my selenium ruby script, I need to add require 'rmagick' to be able to use methods supported by rmagick. Could you please kindly give me more info of Magick so that I can use it? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you have the right details. Image Magick can sometimes be difficult to install, but the basic process is simple: Install the library first (details depend on your OS - check at http://www.imagemagick.org/ ), then install `rmagick` gem same as any other gem in your project (a normal practice is to add it to your project `Gemfile` and use `bundle install`). The gem binds to the library, but otherwise is a normal gem in use (many other gems do similar library bindings).

Comment: Perfect! I did it successfully as your guide. A very big thanks, Neil Slater.